# What version number is considered as stable from composer?

Tags: composer-php, semantic-versioning

I would like to know, if e.g. `0.1.0` is already stable concerning a composer install.
I am familar with the SemVer Tags and I know, that the API can change with every realease which is not the first major (1.0.0) but still: the tag is a fixed state of the project.

So, will composer consider such a tag as stable or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a semantic versioning perspective, it is not stable. However, Composer will treat (almost) all tags as having stability "stable".

Good to know: the `^` operator behaves very similarly to the `~` operator but it sticks closer to semantic versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example `^1.2.3` is equivalent to `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0` as none of the releases until 2.0 should break backwards compatibility. **For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats `^0.3` as `>=0.3.0 <0.4.0`.**

For more information, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md